# Why does my model only converge when I add a MaxPooling with stride of 1 layer at the beginning?

Tags: keras, tensorflow

I have a model that takes an input of inertial sensor data collected at 60 hertz and outputs one of two classes. I have broken the data into 1 min snapshots which seems to be appropriate. I have split the data into training and validation sets. As a baseline, 64% of my data is class 1 versus class 2. I am using keras + tensorflow.

I have tested out two first layers. One is a Conv1D with a kernel_size of (6,) [model performs at baseline] and the other is a MaxPooling1D with a pool_size of (1,) [performs near ideal at close to 92%]. My working assumption is that a MaxPooling layer of kernel size 1 should not do anything of significance but somehow the model does not converge unless I add this layer. Can someone help me understand how adding a MaxPooling1D layer with a pool_size of 1 would help my model converge?

```
if MAX_POOL_FIRST:
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(1, ), input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(Conv1D(16, kernel_size=(6, ), activation='relu'))
else:
    model.add(Conv1D(16, kernel_size=(6, ), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
```

Comment: What is the type and range of the time series? For example (float, [-1, 1]) or (int, [-100, 100])

Comment: What's the input_shape of your data? This is very strange, trying to replicate.

Comment: Can you `print(model.summary())` for each model separately to see the difference in number of parameters?

Comment: I am trying to replicate this myself. I think it was user error.